# Arrray of objects store same attributes in key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a javascript array of objects. Inside the objects i want one key with all the attributes associated with that key in the same bucket.

For example food[{fruits: 'apples', 'bananas'}, {spices: 'chili', 'cajun'}]

If the key is unique then add to the array otherwise just place in the same bucket.

Code below

```
$('.options li').each(function() {
  $name = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $attr = $(this).attr('data-attr');
  food[$name] = $attr;
});
```

Here is what i have code wise https://jsfiddle.net/fqyt18y7/

Comment: I need to associate the name of the food

Comment: fruits -- > apples, bananas; 
spices --> chili, cajun
How would I create this with the code?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but I have updated your fiddle since the one you posted was broken.  https://jsfiddle.net/fqyt18y7/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqyt18y7/6/)**

To achieve this, you need to store each keyword with an *array* of its elements. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('.options li').each(function() {
  $name = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $attr = $(this).attr('data-attr');

  // Check to see if this keyword has been used before
  // because if not, we need to store an empty array there
  if(typeof food[$name] === 'undefined'){
    food[$name] = [];
  }

  // Add our element to that array
  food[$name].push($attr);
});
```

Comment: @Phreak Glad I could help!

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as it allows me (2mins)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object can contain key, value pairs but not one key and multiple values, like you specified [{fruits: 'apples', 'bananas'}, {spices: 'chili', 'cajun'}].

Instead you can change your value to an array, which can contain multiple elements,

[{fruits: **[**'apples', 'bananas'**]**}, {spices: **[**'chili', 'cajun'**]**}].

To achieve this, you need to change

```
 food[$name] = $attr;
```

with

```
 if (!food[$name]) {
    food[$name] = [$attr];
  } else {
    food[$name].push($attr);
  }
```

Hers's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqyt18y7/2/)

Comment: Got it so create a new array of the type